# Hadoop installation Issue:Permission denied

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop2

I followed this [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu) for installation of Hadoop. Unfortunately, when I run the `dfs namenode -format` script - The following error was printed on console:

but at the end i see this msg

```
dfs namenode -format

WARNING: /home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/logs does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/logs’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/logs. Aborting.
```

thank u
also when i run

```
./start-dfs.sh

Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: WARNING: /home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/logs does not exist. Creating.
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [blabla]
blabla: Warning: Permanently added 'blabla,192.168.100.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Comment: I suggest you follow the official Apache Hadoop install guide or use Apache Ambari

Comment: hey there thank u i will ckeck it right now

Comment: hey there
thank u again Sir but i create that name hdoop it's okay

Answer (score 0):

change the permission of `/home/hdoop` to the correct one!

Comment: hey there thank you for your comment hossein
but what u mean by change the premession i now that i don't have the right to change and delete the any coomand cause i try all chmod chown to the root one

Comment: this is my ls -la permission 
        4 drwxr-xr-x 10 hdoop hdoop      4096 Jul 20 08:04 hadoop-3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

i sloved this [link here](https://www.edureka.co/community/72024/format-namenode-could-class-djava-library-hadoop-hadoop-native)
According to my configuration i didn't set `JAVA_HOME` within PATH

```
$ which java
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Also,i change the value of HADOOP_OPTS in `hadoop-env.sh` as given below.

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/"
```

the image before and after [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create** **Directory** :- Create "**logs**" directory by using root access   yourself.As in this case directory was `logs` create it at `/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/`  (eg. "/home/{username}/{extracted hadoop directory}/" )
2. **Give Access of Directory** :- Make it accessible by using `sudo chmod 777 {directory location}`
   In this case - `sudo chmod 777 /home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.2/logs`  To see it worked in my case see following image :
   [solved it by giving access of following directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNAMp.jpg)